# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" ?

Tags: пунктуация

Ты относишься ко мне(,) как к беспомощному ребенку.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя есть правило (пересказываю по памяти): Сравнительный оборот не выделяется запятыми, если обозначает приравнивание, отождествение одного предмета с другим. В Вашем предложении смысл такой: "Ты относишься ко мне, отождествляя меня с беспомощным ребенком". Следовательно, запятая не нужна.